# Apache Superset not running

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I am trying to run Apache Superset locally. I am following [these instructions](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose/).
When I write the command "docker compose up", all the containers seem to be running okay, but when I check the browser on localhost 8088, I just get a loading page:[image].

With the command `docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up`, the page loads.

What I want to do at the end of the day is to modify superset's frontend.

Comment: If you want to modify the frontend code, you should run backend and frontend separately as stated in this instruction: https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#flask-server

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, restarting the docker service fixed it.  Are you running the default SQLITE database or a local instance of a database?

Comment: I am literally forking, cloning the repo. Then I run `docker-compose-up` and nothing more. It stays there forever. The docker compose non dev seems to load but I still can't see any changes

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and pulled a different version (2.0.0-dev) of the image instead of the default latest as the latest docker image has lots of bugs:

Modify the docker compose file with "x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:2.0.0-dev",

Use Postgre v10 on the db section.
db:
env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
image: postgres:10